# How to get the newly add Id from MySql in Blazor using Dapper

Tags: c#, mysql, blazor-server-side

I'm new to blazor and even to asp, and I have learned from the internet how to use Dapper and update and delete data, however, I would like to insert a new record to the MySql database and get the newly inserted Id.
I use the following code for updating and deleting.

```
public Task SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters, string connectionstring)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            return connection.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters);
           
        }
    }
```

Can you help me achieve this, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Managed to solve the problem by adjusting the code like this:-

```
public async Task<int> InsertData<T>(string sql, T parameters, string connectionstring)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            var newId = await connection.QueryAsync<int>(sql + "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();", parameters);
            return newId.Single(); 
        }
    }
```

and the insert string like this:
in the razor component:

```
var sql= @"INSERT INTO countries (Name,Remarks,IsDeleted) VALUES (@Name,@Remarks,@IsDeleted);";
                    int CountryId = await _fetchData.InsertData(sql, new {Name = CountryName, Remarks = Remarks, IsDeleted= false},_config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions what is in your sql parameter, you can do this:

```
string sql = @"
INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([Stuff]) VALUES (@Stuff);
SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)";
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to return the int value in the blazor component, is the point!!

Comment: Sorry it was not entirely clear from your question, would you like to return only the Id or would the entire object <T> work best for you? 
If only the Id and still carrying on from my answer, you would change your method to:
public async Task<int> SaveData<T>(string sql, T parameters, string connectionstring)

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear enough, I would like to insert the record to MySql Table and get the Id returned to use it to do another task in the razor component.